# Using API To Post Links Does Not Include Picture, Title or Meta Desc PHP

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-wall

When posting using the API i receive this:

https://www.facebook.com/weather.warnings/posts/329128793830700

notice how the Title, thumbnail and meta description are missing from the thing.

The following is the code i am using.

```
$allalert = array
(
'oauth_token' => 'not pasting this thanks :P',
'message' => "New $type for $where",
'link' => $url,
);
$sendalert = $facebook->api('/125291287567922/links/','POST',$allalert);
```

Referencing [how does one post a thumbnail picture to a Facebook /links object?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/6327996/how-does-one-post-a-thumbnail-picture-to-a-facebook-links-object) it says the item pulls the picture from the page itself

thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by passing the following items in the array:

```
'name' => "post title",
'link' => "url to the page",
'message'=> "message",
'description' => "longer description",
'picture'=>"url of the picture",
'caption' => "Another bit of text"
```

This removes any reliance on the FB scraper to go out to the url and scrape and parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the needed og tags to your page.

Comment: The OG tags are there.... look at the header section of the linked page.

http://warningweather.com/view/2012-KUNR-SV-W-0053@Severe-Thunderstorm-Warning